# JQuery Masonry & Infinite Scroll - How to scroll content from specific page URL?

Tags: jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I have implemented JQuery Masonry into my portfolio website and I am also utilizing the Infinite Scroll feature.

JQuery Masonry Homepage: http://masonry.desandro.com/ 
Portfolio page with working Infinite Scroll: http://www.owenprescott.com/3d-digital-art.php

In order to append the next set of images it is instructed to create new html "pages" like this: `2.html`, `3.html`, `4.html` and so on (organised numerical order). The problem is most of my site is `.PHP` not `.HTML` and I use includes etc to structure the site. I am hoping to find a way around having to label the pages in the above numerical order (& .HTML) and instead use the existing semantic PHP structure that describes the projects with keywords in the URL.

I hope this is an understandable dilemma I am putting across, I am still learning JQuery so I might struggle with the appropriate terminology. To put this another way, if you open the Masonry project files, how would you alter the code so that you append content for specific URL as below.

Pages:

```
2.html - - - > /conceptual-urban-architecture-3d.php <br>
3.html - - - > /futuristic-outdoor-architecture-3d.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "[path](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/wiki/Options#path)" option:

```
path: function(pageNumber) {
    return "/your/custom/url";
}
```